# how to solve this ArgumentsRequired: binance amount must be greater than minimum amount precision of 3

Tags: javascript, ccxt

```
        const direction = directions[0]
        const TRADE_SIZE = 0.002
        const amount = TRADE_SIZE / marketPrice
        const quantity = Number(amount.toFixed(2))

        await binance.createMarketOrder('BNB/USDT', direction, quantity)
```

My quantity is greater than 0.001, but I still get the error:
ArgumentsRequired: binance amount of BNB/USDT must be greater than minimum amount precision of 3.

I have read the ccxt doc, but nothing can solve my problem.

Comment: `My quantity is greater than 0.001` - Are you sure? Bcoz, from what I see, it's 0.